# How to copy a table from the web to my powerpoint

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, web

I hope the title is self-explanatory enough. Basically what I want to do is to copy a table from the web directly into the powerpoint that I am making. But the result is a bunch of texts with no table format. Is there an easy way to get the information from the web directly into my powerpoint project besides manually typing in the data or taking a screenshot?

Just for the sake of reproduction, [this](https://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/teach-ielts/test-information/scores-explained) is the website that I am trying to copy a table from

Comment: You could copy and paste as an image?

Comment: Thanks for your timely reply. But this is not what I wanted. Because I am trying to edit the table later.

Comment: I've just copied the data and pasted into a text editor. Apart from the headings the rest of the data is tab delimited so you should be able to paste into excel. Tidy up the headers and then read [Insert Excel data in PowerPoint - PowerPoint](https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/insert-excel-data-in-powerpoint-0690708a-5ce6-41b4-923f-11d57554138d)

Answer (score 1):

Yes. This is very much achievable.

For this, you need to go to [Google Docs](https://docs.google.com) and create a new spread sheet. In the top left box, type in this:

`=IMPORTHTML("https://takeielts.britishcouncil.org/teach-ielts/test-information/scores-explained", "table", 0)`

where 0 is perhaps the index number of the 1st table in case there are more than one table (not much sure about it).

When you are done doing this, you will get a table like this:

[image]

Now that you have got a well structured data, you can use it to your convenience and can place it in an excel sheet or use it in a PowerPoint table. If you think this technique will be helpful for future use, you can permanently integrate google sheets into PowerPoint as well by following this  link: [Google Sheets PPT integration](https://www.presentationpoint.com/blog/google-sheets-powerpoint-integration/)

I hope this helps :)